# rewriting URL path with PHP

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I have found many ways of solving my problem I try many of them, some work others not. so I couldn't get the finale solution I'm looking for.

so I have a website with every restaurants in every city, cites in index page, then types, then, restaurants.

city path /sub/city.php?city=11

type path /sub/type.php?city=11&type=22

restaurants path /sub/restaurants.php?r=name

i want to be

```
/11
/11/22
/11/22/restaurantsName
```

i understand there is a way by .htaccess but nothing changes,

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /city.php?city=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ /$2 [L]
```

i also tried another way by redirecting all paths to index.php and then from there i redirect each to its path, but i don't understand how to redirect them to /11 if there is no /11!

```
    $path = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');    
    $urlarray = explode('/', $path);                
    print_r($urlarray);
    
    if(!empty($urlarray[0])){ 
        //header("Location: /index.php"); 
        //exit();
    } else if (!empty($urlarray[1])){
    header("Location: /11"); 
        //exit();
    }
```

please help or **redirect** me to a solution,

Answer (score 0):

## Remove the php extension from the filename

## Disable directory browsing

Options -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)$ /sub/city.php?city=$1
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ /sub/type.php?city=$1&type=$2
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9A-Za-z]+)$ /sub/restaurants.php?r=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

It work for me

Comment: i have tried it, not working! i don't no why!